# How to escape wildcards in parameterized queries with a LIKE statement customized using `sqliteCreateFunction`?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, escaping

I use PDO with SQLite, and want to implement case-insensitive matching for unicode strings.

I have found [this](http://blog.amartynov.ru/archives/php-sqlite-case-insensitive-like-utf8/):

```
function lexa_ci_utf8_like($mask, $value) {
    $mask = str_replace(
        array("%", "_"),
        array(".*?", "."),
        preg_quote($mask, "/")
    );
    $mask = "/^$mask$/ui";
    return preg_match($mask, $value);
}

$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('like', "lexa_ci_utf8_like", 2);
```

I need to use it with untrusted text, so I use parametrized queries.

The problem is that the untrusted text can contain wildcards like `%` or `_`, and I don't want them to behave as wildcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
function lexa_ci_utf8_like($mask, $value) {
    return preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($mask, '/') . '$/ui', $value);
}
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('like', "lexa_ci_utf8_like", 2);
```

will do the trick, because the SQL wildcards `%` and `_` aren't regular expression wildcards, and `preg_quote` escapes regular expression characters from untrusted text.

**Testcases**

```
SELECT 'à' like 'À'     // 1   Just testing if utf8 works
SELECT 'aa' like '%a';  // 0   `%` not used as wildcard!
SELECT 'aa' like '_a';  // 0   `_` not used as wildcard!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the percentage sign to be part of the string parameter, surround it with square brackets.  Do this with your application code before you send the parameter to the database.